# I executed this code to get reverse of a input string without changing the position of spaces in c

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j;
    char or[20];
    printf("enter your input string\n");
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", &or);
    for(i=0;i<20;i++)//to get length of string
    {
    if(or[i]=='\0')
    j=i;
    }
    char rev[j];//reverse string
    for(i=0;i<j ;i++){//inserting spaces into reverse string
    if(or[i]==' ')
    {
    rev[i]=or[i];
    }
    }
    for(i=0;i<j; i++)//inserting characters of original string into reverse string
    {
    if(or[i]!=' '){
    if(rev[j-i]!=' '){
    rev[j-i]=or[i];
    }
    }
    }
    printf ("%s", rev);//printing reverse string
 return 0;
}
```

[enter link description here](https://www.onlinegdb.com/edit/SsmASenJP)

in codeblocks it takes input but before showing output
process returned 3.
are any changes needed in code or in IDE?

my input is: hi dude
my expected output is : ed udih
but i get output like this : enter your input string

hi dude

Comment: Help us help you. Share some sample input, the output you're expecting for it, and the output you actually got.

Comment: In addition, please format your code with proper indentation to make it more readable.

Comment: `char rev[j];` should be `char rev[j + 1];` ... and remember `rev` is not initialized. You set some of its elements to space, but the others contain *junk* ("junk" may be space!!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your algorithm is wrong from inception.

- The content of the variable-length array is only set on encounter of a space; the remaining content is indeterminate, and therefore any evaluation tests against invoke undefined behaviour.
- The actual reversal storage is wrong. You're advancing the "write" position on each iteration even when you skip an actual write. You need different indexing here.

One plausible solution is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char or [20];
    printf("enter your input string\n");
    if (scanf("%19[^\n]%*c", or ) == 1)
    {
        size_t len = strlen(or);

        char rev[len+1];//reverse string
        for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
            rev[i] = (or[i] == ' ') ? ' ' : 0;
        rev[len] = 0;

        for (size_t i = len, k=0; i-- > 0;)
        {
            // find next 'write' positon. note this will
            //  do nothing if we're already on top of a
            //  position ready for storing.
            while (rev[k] == ' ')
                ++k;
            
            // write next char and advance writer index (k)
            if (or [i] != ' ') {
                rev[k++] = or[i];
            }
        }
        printf("%s", rev);//printing reverse string
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Input**

```
one two three four
```

**Output**

```
ruo fee rhtow teno
```

[See it live here](https://godbolt.org/z/T816j4PdM)